# Rewrite url from php file to any virtual directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am struggling with the rewriting of files to virtual directories. I googled already a lot but nothing what I've tried worked for me so there is maybe something wrong with the rest of my .htaccess or just in conflict with those rules.

**What do I want to achieve:**

```
Rewrite https://www.domain.com/index.php -> https://www.domain.com/
Rewrite https://www.domain.com/page.php -> https://www.domain.com/any-pagename/
```

**My current htaccess (http->https and non-www to www) and my try to achieve my first goal:**

```
# Deflate Compression by MimeType
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css)$">
  ExpiresActive on
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# First rewrite to HTTPS:
# Don't put www. here. If it is already there it will be included, if not
# the subsequent rule will catch it.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# Here I want to rewrite my https://www.domain.com/index.php
RewriteRule ^/ index.php [L]
Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You last rule seems to be faulty. Replace that with this rule:

```
# Here I want to rewrite my https://www.domain.com/index.php

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Tested this. This hasn't changed something in my browser's address bar but it "destroyed" the css and images. I can only see the DOM with its content now.

Comment: **destroyed** is quite a heavy word for a this poor rewrite rule, check chrome dev tool to see why css/js is not loading (this rule us ignoring real files and directories anyway). Also this is NOT for changing URL in browser, it just rotes everything to `index.php` in current directory.

Comment: Uncaught Syntaxerror: Unexpected Token is the error.

Comment: And that has no relation to this rewrite rule.

Comment: Well when I delete this htaccess line it works again.

Comment: I wrote about this rule not your full .htaccess. I just provided you a corrected rule that you already had in your .htaccess and you have lot of other stuff in your .htaccess

Comment: Now it works without any error, but when I access "https://www.domain.com" it should redirect to ""https://www.domain.com/index.php"  if I understood you right or ? This doesn't work for me atm.

Comment: For that to happen just add `DirectoryIndex index.php` line on top of your .htaccess. Now URL won't change but it will load `http://domain.com/index.php`